# Transfer domain out of Azure

Tags: azure

I have a domain name that I registered with Azure a couple of years back. I decided to transfer the domain out to another registrar. I've successfully gone through the transfer, but I can still see the domain as a resource in the Azure portal. Can I safely delete the domain resource now?

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting the domain resource from the portal:

- Reconfirm the successful domain transfer with the new registrar as
  you mentioned this is done its good to double-check.
- Check and update DNS settings with the new registrar if needed.
- Also Verify there are no active billing or subscription dependencies.
  Consider contacting Azure support for guidance if unsure
  if you are still unaware of this its better to contact support of azure before deleting it with uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and deleted the domain from the portal. So far no issues, so I'm gonna assume that it is OK to delete the domain resource itself.